VBA concatenate non-blank textboxes based on case/criteria - getting compile error within array
Looking to streamline code for an email subject line (txtEmailSubLine). I need two versions because the email subject line is slightly different depending upon which order type is selected from a drop down (cboOrderType). The email subject line is a result of concatenating eight textboxes with "_" delimiter between each.
Instead of eight lines copy/pasted into several click events (see OLD CODE below). I would like the new code in a regular module and Call it from various procedures in the user form module.
I have two, textbox arrays, to create two unique email subject lines based on the combo box selection. I also want blank textboxes to be ignored.
I'm stuck, because I'm getting a Compile Error: Variable Not Defined. It is highlighting the first textbox in the first array, txtSO. If I remove it, then it highlights the next one and so on.
Help would be greatly appreciated.
'OLD CODE IN USERFORM MODULE
Private Sub cmbSave_Click()
    'Next eight lines of code populates txtEmailSubLine
    If txtShopOrdNum <> "" Then txtEmailSubLine = txtShopOrdNum
    If txtSO <> "" Then txtEmailSubLine = txtEmailSubLine & "_SO " & txtSO.Value
    If txtPO <> "" Then txtEmailSubLine = txtEmailSubLine & "_PO " & txtPO.Value
    If txtPOAmt <> "" Then txtEmailSubLine = txtEmailSubLine & "_" & txtPOAmt.Value
    If txtProposal <> "" Then txtEmailSubLine = txtEmailSubLine & "_" & txtProposal.Value
    If txtNickname <> "" Then txtEmailSubLine = txtEmailSubLine & "_" & txtNickname.Value
    If txtEUNickname <> "" Then txtEmailSubLine = txtEmailSubLine & "_" & txtEUNickname.Value
    If txtSys <> "" Then txtEmailSubLine = txtEmailSubLine & "_" & txtSys.Value
'END OF OLD CODE

'NEW CODE IN USERFORM MODULE
Private Sub cmbSave_Click()
   Call EmailSubLine
End Sub

'NEW CODE IN REGULAR MODULE
Option Explicit
Option Base 1 'forces the array having Lbound = 1 to match the textbox index.
Sub EmailSubLine()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim c As Variant
    Dim txtShopOrdNum, txtEmailSubLine, txtSO, txtPO, txtPOAmt, txtProposal, txtNickname, txtEUNickname, txtSys, cboOrderType As String 'I needed to Dim all of the textboxes, which took care of the compile error - however the code is not populating txtEmailSubLine
    Dim strCon As String 'concatenate in txtEmailSubLine
     b = Array(txtSO, txtPO, txtPOAmt, txtProposal, txtNickname, txtEUNickname, txtSys)
     c = Array(txtSO, txtPO, txtPOAmt, txtProposal, txtNickname, txtEUNickname, cboOrderType)
     
    strCon = txtShopOrdNum
   
    Select Case cboOrderType.Value
        Case "System" Or "System IC"
                For i = 1 To 7
                    If b(i) <> vbNullString Then
                        strCon = strCon & "_" & b(i)
                End If
                Next
                txtEmailSubLine.Value = strCon
        Case "Service" Or "Repair"
                For i = 1 To 7
                    If c(i) <> vbNullString Then
                        strCon = strCon & "_" & c(i)
                End If
                Next
                txtEmailSubLine.Value = strCon
    End Select
End Sub


Hello, anyone able to help?
